# CloudKit Zone Deletion and Recreation

Tags: ios, cloudkit

Device A is disconnected (had already previously connected to an iCloud database and successfully synced changes).  This device is now offline and has uncommitted changes (because the app was designed to work offline).

Device B deletes the zone, re-creates it (user wanted to reset it, or more specifically I have tested this using the dashboard, deleting the zone and re-creating it).

When device A comes back online, it starts uploading records (and will eventually fail when it try to modify something but adds defiantly work).  The problem is it may successfully upload records before I can do a reset.

What is the correct way to determine if a zone has been reset?  Just querying if the zone exists doesn't necessarily tell me the zone has been reset.

I believe when I get updates from the subscription I will get a changeTokenExpired error, but I though Apple had said we should upload changes first, then download (but correct me if I am wrong).

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a `CKDatabaseSubscription` or a `CKRecordZoneSubscription` and save it to the database.

When a record zone is deleted, your app delegate's `application(didReceiveRemoteNotification:)` will be invoked.

Use the `userInfo` dictionary you receive there to create a `CKDatabaseSubscription` or `CKRecordZoneSubscription` using the `init(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary:)` constructor.

Hope that helps!